# ReactJS not fetching data from server when using 'url' attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner of ReactJS and just starting with [the example code on React's official site](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html). When I'm trying the code in section ['Fetching from the server'](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#fetching-from-the-server), I can't get it to work.

I've tried both relative path

```
React.render(
  <CommentBox url="../data/data.json" />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

and absolute path

```
React.render(
  <CommentBox url="http://localhost/path/to/data.json" />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

But **none** of them has run correctly.
When I checked out the Network panel in Chrome dev tool, I saw the page didn't even send the request for `data.json`. Thus I got an error of `Cannot read property 'comments' of undefined`.

more code:

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        from {this.props.author} <br/>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.comments.map(function(comment){
      return (
        <Comment author={comment.author}>
          {comment.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    return (
    <div className="comment-list">
      {commentNodes}
    </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="comment-form">
        Hello, I am a comment form.
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="comment-box">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList comments={this.props.data.comments} />
        <CommentForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

// ==========  This won't work  ===========
// React.render(
//   <CommentBox url="./data/data.json" />,
//   document.getElementById('content')
// );

// =========== This works. ===========
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "./data/data.json",
  dataType: "json",
}).done(function(res){
  React.render(
    <CommentBox data={res} />,
    document.getElementById('content')
  );
});
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share more of your code? Are you making an `GET` request in your component to retrieve the `JSON` data? Here's a [great example](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) of how to retrieve data from the server.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody REALLY a great example for a beginner like me. Thank you! :)

Comment: I thought exactly the same thing, thanks for your post :) :)

Comment: This is a "me too" comment - thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A little bit further down the page in that React Tutorial, they do an AJAX request in the componentDidMount property of the CommentBox React class.

You need to make an AJAX GET request for the data you want in the componentDidMount function in your CommentBox class.

Comment: Thank you! I thought React would do some magic with the `url` attribute and get the data... totally wrong... Thank you for your tip. I get it now :)  Really should've read through the article before asking a question.

Answer (score 5):

The [React docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html) recommend performing a `GET` request in `componentDidMount()` and storing the data in state.

First, initialize the data variables:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    dataVar1: ''
  };
}
```

Then fetch the data using `$.get()`:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  $.get('URL-TO-FETCH-DATA-FROM', function(result) {
    if (this.isMounted()) {
      this.setState({
        dataVar1: result
      });
    }
  }.bind(this));
}
```

where [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) is the jQuery AJAX shorthand function. In `render()` the data can then be displayed:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.dataVar1}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Good example of using a jQuery ajax call with React. Thanks.